# How to create a shape with a hole in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, shapes

I want to create a kind of masking layer which consists of a black area with holes in it. Through the holes it should be possible to see the background. In the simplest version I it's just an rectangle covering the whole screen with an opening in the middle. As shown in the sample picture below.

[image: What I want to realize with QML]

My first approach was to use QML's Context2D feature: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html. Maybe it's totally wrong to do it this way, but maybe it's a good starting point. I tried to create an rectangle (which works) and a clipping area (which doesn't work). Besides the fact my implementation of the clipping doesn't work I would have the problem that the clip() command erases the area outside its path but not inside (at least that's what I understood from the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#clip-method).

```
Canvas {

    anchors.fill: parent

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "black"

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, Sizes.rootWindow.width, Sizes.rootWindow.height);
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

Comment: Create 4 rectangles as a borders if you want some simple solution.

Comment: Look into OpacityMask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself by rereading the Qt docs. There is a function to create transparent rectangles inside a given canvas which is called "clearRect(...)": https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#clearRect-method

```
Canvas {

    anchors.fill: parent

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "black"

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.clearRect(10, 10, 600, 100)

    }
```

---

For more advanced shapes [OpacityMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) suggested by [Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld) is definitely the way to solve this. But for rectangle I think my solution is more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

if the hole is exactly centered and the borders are all have the same size, you could use a transparent rectangle with borders:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "transparent"
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 50
}
```

Comment: I want to create arbitrarily placed rectangles. Maybe my graphical example was over simplified and misleading in this way.